# where is embedded tomcat picking up war from?

Tags: tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm working on an API that runs locally via embedded tomcat -
org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.  This is not-spring boot.  It works fine for me & most developers.  For one developer tomcat is not picking up the latest built war's. It keeps running an older version of the app. Where can I look to see what war or jars are being loaded by tomcat?

It's a little confusing since it all works fine for me & he is running the same project version I checked into git.

Comment: It doesn't. It uses the classes and resources from the class path (or as you have configured the embedded tomcat). But it doesn't use a war.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a call to one of the `Tomcat.addWebapp()` methods in your code. The `docBase` (the location of the WAR file) will be the second of the two String parameters. (The different methods have different parameters but they all have two String parameters and the `docBase` is always the second one).